# Passing arguments to add_argument as a dictionary

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program in Python 3.8 which takes multiple different commands (e.g. `mode`), each of which have a different valid constellation of the same options (i.e., one option might be only valid in two commands, another in all of them, etc.) I therefore want to define each option (say `--my-arg`) once, as a argument dictionary (e.g. `my_arg`), and then pass it to multiple `add_argument` calls as appropriate for each command using `**`. But for some reason, the `option_strings` is being dropped in the call, and I don't know why.

Minimum reproducible example:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Test keyword arguments')
arg_parser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='what_to_run')
parser_mode = arg_parser.add_parser('mode')
my_arg = {'option_strings': ['--my-arg'], 'dest': 'my_arg',
             'help': 'My string argument goes here'}
parser_mode.add_argument(**my_arg)
parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
```

This is the latter part of the output:

```
>>> parser_mode.add_argument(**my_arg)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='my_arg', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='My string argument goes here', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
usage: Test keyword arguments [-h] {mode} ...
Test keyword arguments: error: unrecognized arguments: --my-arg
```

Note that `option_strings` is `[]`, when `['--my-arg']` is expected.

If instead I replicate the option as a positional argument and remove it from the dictionary, it works:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Test keyword arguments')
arg_parser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='what_to_run')
parser_mode = arg_parser.add_parser('mode')
my_arg = {'dest': 'my_arg', 'help': 'My string argument goes here'}
parser_mode.add_argument('--my-arg', **my_arg)
parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
```

Output:

```
>>> parser_mode.add_argument('--my-arg', **my_arg)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--my-arg'], dest='my_arg', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='My string argument goes here', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
Namespace(my_arg='my value', what_to_run='mode')
```

This is a tolerable fix, I suppose (I guess I could write a function to do this for me...), but I beyond wanting to eliminate duplication, I want to understand what's going on.

Comment: Because it's a positional argument, not a keyword argument. `add_argument` has no arguments named `option_strings`.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is confusing you? You need to pass the CLI arg as a positional – ``**my_arg`` does not (cannot!) do that.

Comment: OK -- interesting. It accepts the keyword 'option_strings'; if I use something like 'name' or 'flags', it gives me an error when I invoke `add_argument`.

Comment: `_StoreAction` _does_ have a keyword argument named `option_strings`. The value you pass gets erased here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2c8a0027e5555e371c1293f26b3262000b8cfe8a/Lib/argparse.py#L1527-L1528.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Niiiiice.  Thanks for finding it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't get there from here. I am opting to use a helper function:

```py
import argparse
def add_argument(parser, kwargs):
    return parser.add_argument(*(kwargs['option_strings']), **kwargs)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Test keyword arguments')
arg_parser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='what_to_run')
parser_mode = arg_parser.add_parser('mode')
my_arg = {'option_strings': ['--my-arg'], 'dest': 'my_arg',
             'help': 'My string argument goes here'}
add_argument(parser_mode, my_arg)
parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
```

Output:

```
>>> add_argument(parser_mode, my_arg)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--my-arg'], dest='my_arg', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='My string argument goes here', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['mode', '--my-arg', 'my value'])
Namespace(my_arg='my value', what_to_run='mode')
```

Thanks to those who commented.